# How to find the value for which the function is maximum (implementation code )?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to solve the following problem: i have this function:

[image]

with I0(k) being this function:

[image].

In each step in my code, i have a known, different angle for the cosine and i want each time to know: for which k the function is maximum. Mathematically, i have to calculate the derivative, to set it equal to zero and to solve the equation. But how is it possible to implement that with tensorflow? What is the best way to solve this problem please ?

Comment: please add the pictures to the question instead of links.

Comment: I am very sorry but I am totally new here and when trying to embed pictures I receive the error message "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." ... :(